# GoLang Sruct to JSON not converting

Tags: json, struct, go

I am trying to convert my struct "Sim" into JSON, after being filled with data.

When I print the var s, it shows correct information, when I print data, it shows blank.

How do I convert Struct to JSON?

Reduced Code Below:

```
type Sim struct {
    yr, ag, av, db, wd, st []int
    withdrawal []string
}

func main() {
    // Creating simulation
    var s Sim

    // Filling with data
    s = simulate(15000, 60, 65, 90, 2015, 10.0, 140000.0, true, s)

    // Converting to JSON, for transmission over web
    data, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Data is correct
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Prints: {}
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Comment: This is possible the 300th question about JSON (un)marshaling with non-exported fields. Meta-question: Is really nobody able to find this information in the documentation of package encoding/json? Is this so complicated to find on SO? Why is this beeing asked over and over again?

Comment: Honestly, I read like 5 questions and it wasn't until directly after I posted mine, that I found one talking about the required Caps on it.  I even watched a talk on it by Google Engineers, they used caps, but didn't explain the significance of that decision.

Comment: Also, I have written plenty of code in my life, while many languages use caps to denote meaning, I've never seen one strongly enforced like this.

Comment: It is the third page of the "Basics" chapter in the Go Tour: http://tour.golang.org/basics/3 . (And the Basics chapter is the first after the Welcome chapter.) The whole Tour covers almost everything needed to know and takes maybe two hours.

Comment: Right, and I went through the tour when I started.  But that didn't really click.  It still doesn't make sense that they use caps to determine private v public methods.

Comment: All languages have some seemingly arbitrary rules to learn. I could say it doesn't make sense that exported identifiers need to be redeclared in separate header files for some languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in your structures starts with lower case so they are not marshalled to JSON. Make them start with upper case letter.

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

type Sim struct {
    Yr, Ag, Av, Db, Wd, St []int
    Withdrawal             []string
}

func main() {
    // Creating simulation
    var s Sim

    // Converting to JSON, for transmission over web
    data, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Data is correct
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Prints: {}
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/lQ6EanAG0E)</kbd>

[JSON serialization in GO](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go)

Comment: Yep, you beat me to it, I just realized that.  Thanks!  (I'll accept in 3 min once timer allows)